# How to update screen in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, uicomponents

i am developing one app. and i am facing a problem related to updating the screen,which is already in stack.I tried to use myappscreen.invalidate() on button click,but it doesn't update screen.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your screen the active screen?

To redraw the active screen, you should just need to call the invalidate() method to cause the screen to refresh.

Where are you calling invalidate() from?  You cannot call invalidate() from a Timer thread unless you have got an eventlock.

Comment: the API says an opposite thing about `invalidate()` and event lock: "It is safe to call this function without synchronizing on the event lock."

Comment: You are correct that you can call invalidate() without the event lock if all you are doing is invalidating.  If you are updating any components/fields etc, then you do need to hold the event lock.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update screen then override activate() of UiApplication and write code in that which you want to update.